# ASPX Write to SQL Datatypes

Tags: sql, asp.net

I want to write to my SQL databse, but getting this specific error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the
>   scalar variable "@Aantalpaginas". at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at
>   project.NEWANDWRITE.btnOpslaan_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in 
>   Error Number:137,State:2,Class:15

This are my datatypes in SQL: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeFSk.jpg

I think i need to convert the text in the txtPaginas.text to an int right?

```
if (Page.IsValid)
        {

            string connString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["csBoeken"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);

            string sqlWegschrijven = "INSERT INTO TabelBoeken (ISBN, Titel, Auteur, Uitgever, JaarUitgifte, Aantalpaginas, Aanschafprijs) VALUES (@ISBN, @Titel, @Auteur, @Uitgever, @JaarUitgifte, @Aantalpaginas, @Aanschafprijs)";

            SqlCommand cmdSchrijfNaarDB = new SqlCommand(sqlWegschrijven, myConnection);

            cmdSchrijfNaarDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titel", txtTitel.Text);
            cmdSchrijfNaarDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Auteur", txtAuteur.Text);
            cmdSchrijfNaarDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISBN", txtISBN.Text);
            cmdSchrijfNaarDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uitgever", txtUitgever.Text);
            cmdSchrijfNaarDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JaarUitgifte", txtJaar.Text);
            cmdSchrijfNaarDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Aantalpagina", txtPagina.Text);
            cmdSchrijfNaarDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Aanschafprijs", txtPrijs.Text);

            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                cmdSchrijfNaarDB.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                lblError.Text = error.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                myConnection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a spelling error on parameter #6

```
if (Page.IsValid)
    {

        string connString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["csBoeken"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);

        string sqlWegschrijven = "INSERT INTO TabelBoeken (ISBN, Titel, Auteur, Uitgever, JaarUitgifte, Aantalpaginas, Aanschafprijs) VALUES (@ISBN, @Titel, @Auteur, @Uitgever, @JaarUitgifte, @Aantalpaginas, @Aanschafprijs)";

        SqlCommand cmdSchrijfNaarDB = new SqlCommand(sqlWegschrijven, myConnection);

        cmdSchrijfNaarDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titel", txtTitel.Text);
        cmdSchrijfNaarDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Auteur", txtAuteur.Text);
        cmdSchrijfNaarDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISBN", txtISBN.Text);
        cmdSchrijfNaarDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uitgever", txtUitgever.Text);
        cmdSchrijfNaarDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JaarUitgifte", txtJaar.Text);
        cmdSchrijfNaarDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Aantalpaginas", txtPagina.Text); // Correct spelling is @Aantalpaginas
        cmdSchrijfNaarDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Aanschafprijs", txtPrijs.Text);

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            cmdSchrijfNaarDB.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            lblError.Text = error.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```